# font-awesome fa-thin does not work while fa does

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

On my website, the following code works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css"/>
<i class="fa fa-bars" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
```

However, the following does not (showing a square):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css"/>
<i class="fa-thin fa-bars" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
```

I took the code from this website: https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/bars?f=classic&s=thin

My question is how to make `fa-thin` work.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the documentation you link to, click Getting Started.

This will bring a modal which says:

> This is a Pro icon!
>
> To use the thin style of “bars“, you'll need a subscription to a Pro-level plan or a perpetual Pro license that includes the specific version of Font Awesome in which this icon (or style) was released.

You're using an unofficial third-party CDN which only incudes the free icons.

Comment: Quentin I don't have subscription but I could try and see it in the following link.::  https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-bars

Comment: @mmirbekian — That isn't the same as the code you are using! It uses the free `fa` style, not the `fa-thin` style you are trying to use.

Comment: You are right Quentin .. The code works for normal bars not the thin ones.. we need authorization for the thin